# Is this Black Box Model correct?

Tags: project-management

Is this black box model correct for a Tennis ball launcher please?

Only thing I’m a little unsure about is the Inputs please?

[image]

Comment: Energy + Mechanical Energy = Total Energy (kinetic + gravitational), what do you think is a problem?

Comment: Whether the model is "correct" or not depends a great deal on how you plan to use the model. Since this looks like a school project, I suggest that you ask your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect. It doesn't give a slightest idea that the energy outputs are somehow connected to the movement and placement of the ball.

The ball itself is not an output, the outputs are modifications to the state of the ball. You forgot the initial flying direction. It's included to the impulse that the ball gets (impulse is an exact physics term, not only spoken language). Another forgotten factor is the rotation of the ball. It affects substantially the trajectory as the players know. You could probably well let the outputs of the launcher be only the initial direction, the initial velocity and initial rotation (angular velocities) of the ball. The trajectory needs a bigger system which contains the air, earth (=gravity) obstacles and , of course, all properties the ball initially had + got from the launcher.

The inputs of the launcher are the operating power, the launching trigger signal, all properties of the ball that you see meaningful including placement, material properties and geometry. But not the ball itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here‘s a simpler one, with a different focus:

- input: ball at rest
- output: ball at a certain velocity vector

This one focuses on the launchers main function „to shoot a ball“.

If you want you can add arrows from below to indicate key design factors, like spring force, inclination mechanism etc.

If you want you can indicate hard to control parameters with arrows from the top like wear, time, imprecision, temperature, operators mood etc.

As was already stated, it depends all on what you want to show or illustrate.